# Is SOAP a transport protocol?

Tags: protocol, network-protocols

Is SOAP a transport protocol? if yes could you please explain how it can be defined as a transfer protocol if it's dependant on other application protocols like HTTP and SMTP?

Comment: SOAP is not a transport protocol. For that matter, neither are HTTP and SMTP.

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I mean to say application protocol.

Comment: A very simplified way to explain the dependency on other application layer protocols is that HTTP and SMTP are layer 5 application protocols and SOAP is a layer 7 application layer protocol.

Answer (score 5):

SOAP is not a transport protocol. SOAP is an application layer protocol that relies on other application layer protocols (most commonly HTTP) to transport it. (The application layers are 5-7 in the OSI model, with SOAP usually considered part of layer 7.)

Transport protocols like TCP are more concerned with the reliability of transmitting data through flow control, error checking, guaranteeing delivery.

Answer (score -1):

SOAP is a messaging protocol. Typically, it sits on top of HTTP messaging protocol, but other messaging transports are also possible (e.g. MQ, etc). While both SOAP and HTTP are protocols that belong to Application OSI Layer, from the point of view of SOAP message HTTP is just a "transport" (not to be confused with Transport OSI Layer).

WSDL (Web Service Description Language) distinguishes between two message styles: document and RPC. The message style affects the contents of the SOAP Body:

> Document style:  The SOAP Body contains one or more child elements
> called parts.  There are no SOAP formatting rules for what the body
> contains;  it contains whatever the sender and the receiver agrees
> upon.
>
> RPC style: RPC implies that SOAP body contains an element with the
> name of  the method or operation being invoked. This element in turn
> contains  an element for each parameter of that method/operation.

For applications that use serialization/deserialization to abstract away the data wire format, there is one more choice to be made: the serialization format. There are two popular serialization formats:

> SOAP Encoding:
> SOAP encoding is a set of serialization.  The rules
> specify how objects, structures, arrays, and object graphs  should be
> serialized. Generally speaking, an application using SOAP encoding is
> focused on remote procedure calls and will likely use RPC message style.
>
> When SOAP encoding is used, the SOAP message contains data type
> information within the SOAP message. This makes serialization (data
> translation) easier since the data type of each parameter is denoted
> with the parameter.
>
> Literal:
> Data is serialized according to a schema. In practice, this
> schema is usually expressed using W3C XML Schema. The SOAP message
> does not directly contain any data type information, just a reference
> (namespace) to the schema that is used. To perform proper
> serialization (data translation) both, the sender and the receiver,
> must know the schema and must use the same rules for translating data.

Comment: Nice answer. However since you are clearly referencing material written by someone else, [you need to cite your source(s)](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). Please edit the question and add the appropriate link. Also please have a read through the Help section. That'll tell you how to write good quality answers and questions, among other things.